# Can you stay in Turkey for over 90 days within the 180 day visa period but split over different visits?

Tags: visas, turkey, 90-180-visa-rules

The Turkish e-visa is valid for a period of 180 days and allows you to stay for a maximum of 90 days. Am I allowed to stay for say 50 days, then another 50 days, over two different visits within the 180 day period?

I'm looking at the e-visa website [here](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/arrivaldate/) and it doesn't seem to be too clear on this.

Comment: Note that it's 90 days within the last 180 for each and every day, not 90 days within some arbitary 180 day window that resets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you may not do this.

You are limited to a maximum of 90 days within the 180 day period regardless of how many trips those days occur over.

This is very clearly stated out on the [Turkish Ministry of Foreign Affairs website](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/general-information-about-turkish-visas.en.mfa) :

> - The length of stay provided by visa or visa exemption cannot exceed 90 days within each 180 days. The regulation of 90 days of stay within
>     the last 180 days is binding for all foreigners that will travel to
>     Turkey.

In order to stay longer you will need to apply for a "Short Term Residence Permit" which the link above contains some information about.

Comment: Thanks for the info! A small aside - it is stated that the validity of the visa begins when I enter Turkey. If I wish for the visa to expire sooner, am I allowed to apply for the visa but have the start date be asap but not actually enter the country yet?

Comment: For an e-visa, the validity of the visa starts on the date you enter when you apply for the visa.  I you obtain the visa at the airport (which costs more for most nationalities) then it starts on the day you obtain it.

Comment: Well, it asks for "Arrival Date in Turkey", but I'd like for the e-visa to end as soon as possible after I leave the country for a new 180 day period. Would I encounter any troubles if I set the date to today despite entering sometime next month instead?

Comment: The 180 day period mentioned above is NOT related to the 180 days the visa is valid for.  It is 90 days within ANY 180 day period - even if it covers 2 visa periods.  "90 days of stay within the *last* 180 days"